# pic: does anyone use it for diagrams? is there a version that outputs svg? (vs. troff or TeX)

Tags: graphics

I'm in the middle of reading [More Programming Pearls](http://books.google.com/books?id=a2AZAQAAIAAJ) and read the chapter on the [Pic language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pic_language) (see also [Kernighan's paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.43.2982)) with some interest.

Anyone out there using it? It seems like it might be fairly easily translatable into SVG. There's a GNU version (w/ [docs by Eric Raymond](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.136.8343)!) but it only outputs groff and TeX.

Answer (score 5):

I use it. It's really handy for drawing sequence diagrams, in plain text - which you can then version control.

I've messed about with WYSIWYG UML diagram editors in the past, and have come to the conclusion that plain text is a far more reliable option.

Which would you rather? 80 lines of text or a 500kb zip file containing impenetrable XML?

The language is so so tiny, yet expressive - you can learn it in a day or two.

Use it for:

- Component dependency diagrams
- Flow diagrams
- Sequence diagrams
- Server room layouts
- Floor-plans

Basically... Any diagram which doesn't need to be slapped on a website with a beta/web 2.0 sticker. It's not amazingly beautiful, however, it gets the job done.

More resources:

[Archive of http://www.umlgraph.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20160818005733/http://www.umlgraph.org:80/) from 2016

http://floppsie.comp.glam.ac.uk/Glamorgan/gaius/web/pic.html

Answer (score 3):

aha, looks like esr also wrote a program called [doclifter](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/doclifter/doclifter.html):

> doclifter translates documents written in troff macros to DocBook. Structural subsets of the
> requests in man(7), mdoc(7), ms(7), me(7), mm(7), and troff(1) are supported.
>
> The translation brings over all the structure of the original document at section,
> subsection, and paragraph level. Command and C function synopses are translated into DocBook
> markup, not just a verbatim display. Tables (TBL markup) are translated into DocBook table
> markup. PIC diagrams are translated into SVG. Troff-level information that might have
> structural implications is preserved in XML comments.

edit: even better, GNU [pic2plot](http://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/manual/html_node/plotutils_20.html#SEC20):

> The pic2plot program takes one or more files in the pic language, and either displays the figures that they contain on an X Window System display, or produces an output file containing the figures. Many graphics file formats are supported.
>
> The pic language is a 'little language' that was developed at Bell Laboratories for creating box-and-arrow diagrams of the kind frequently found in technical papers and textbooks. A directory containing documentation on the pic language is distributed along with the plotting utilities. On most systems it is installed as `/usr/share/pic2plot` or `/usr/local/share/pic2plot`. The directory includes Brian Kernighan's original technical report on the language, Eric Raymond's tutorial on the GNU implementation, and some sample pic macros contributed by W. Richard Stevens.